# Get the submit button's id with onsubmit event

Tags: jquery, forms, onsubmit

HTML:

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="post" onsubmit="form_process()">


<input type="submit" id="btn_id" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

javascript snippet :

```
function form_process(){


    $elem = $(this);

    if(window.console){

    console.log(" button id = " + $elem.attr('id'));


    }



}// end if function form_process()
```

But  console shows the `id` as `undefined`. The problem is with selecting the submit button in jQuery. How can I get the submit button's `id` ?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `this` refers global window object. Which is similar to `$(window)`

Option 1:

pass `this` in your form

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="post" 
         id="my-form" onsubmit="form_process(this)">

function form_process(obj){    

    $elem = $(obj).find(input[type="submit"]);
    if(window.console){
      console.log(" button id = " + $elem.attr('id'));
    }

}
```

Option 2: Unobtrusive JS

```
$('#my-form').submit(function(){
  $elem = $(this);
});
```

Comment: let me test and let you know

Comment: Shouldn't there be single quotations around the `find` method's parameter ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following structure;

**HTML:**

```
<form action="javascript:void(0)" method="post">
     <input type="submit" id="btn_id" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
// or you can use class for this form
$('form').on('submit', function() {
     $elem = $(this);
     var id = $elem.children('input[type="submit"]').attr('id');
     if(window.console){
         console.log(" button id = " + id);
     }

});
```

Here is a working fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/cubuzoa/qWvz9/1/**